# Java method with varargs that executes actions and prints known result

Tags: java, java-8, variadic-functions

Is it possible in Java to create method similar to this **execute** method:

```
public void execute(Runnable... mrs) {
    for (Runnable mr : mrs) {
        mr.run();
        // should print some expected string here
    }
}

public void sleep(int seconds) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000 * seconds);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        log.error("Error occured", ex);
    }
}

public void customExecute() {
    execute(() -> sleep(1), () -> sleep(2));
}
```

but after executing each operation it should print passed String parameter and (the key moment of the issue) it should support one line usage - something like:

```
execute(("Action 1 passed") -> someAction(), ("Other action passed") -> otherAction());
```

Comment: You need them to be executed in parallel or sequentially? And, `InterruptedException` doesn't mean an error.

Comment: @Sasha sequentally. In my case there are some long actions after  executing each of them I want to print something in console.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with a variation of the Builder Pattern:

```
public interface Step {
    void doIt(String msg, Runnable r);
    default Step then(String msg, Runnable r) {
        doIt(msg, r);
        return this;
    }
}
public static Step execute(String msg, Runnable r) {
    Step s=(m,x)-> {
        x.run();
        System.out.println(msg);
    };
    return s.then(msg, r);
}
```

then you can use it like

```
execute("Action 1 passed", () -> someAction())
  .then("Other action passed", () -> otherAction());
```

and expand it as you like

```
execute("Action 1 passed", () -> someAction())
  .then("Other action passed", () -> otherAction())
  .then("NextAction passed", () -> nextAction())
  .then("and nextAction passed again", () -> nextAction()) ;
```

It’s also easily adaptable to other execution strategies, e.g.

```
static ExecutorService es=Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
public static Step executeInBackground(String msg, Runnable r) {
    Step s=(m,x)-> es.execute(()-> execute(m, x));
    return s.then(msg, r);
}
```

usable with a tiny change at the caller:

```
executeInBackground("Action 1 passed", () -> someAction())
  .then("Other action passed", () -> otherAction())
  .then("NextAction passed", () -> nextAction())
  .then("and nextAction passed again", () -> nextAction());
```

Answer (score 3):

Java has no special syntax to passing key-value pairs to the method. I see two possible solutions.

#### 1. Create the additional object:

```
static class NamedRunnable implements Runnable {
    Runnable r;
    String title;
    
    public NamedRunnable(String title, Runnable r) {
        this.title = title;
        this.r = r;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        r.run();
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return title;
    }
}

public void execute(NamedRunnable... mrs) {
    for (NamedRunnable mr : mrs) {
        mr.run();
        System.out.println(mr+" completed");
    }
}

public void customExecute() {
    execute(new NamedRunnable("Action 1 passed", () -> sleep(1)), 
            new NamedRunnable("Other action passed", () -> sleep(2)));
}
```

Object-oriented, but not very short.

#### 2. Declare several `execute` methods with different number of arguments.

```
public void execute(String t1, Runnable r1) {
    execute(new NamedRunnable(t1, r1));
}

public void execute(String t1, Runnable r1, String t2, Runnable r2) {
    execute(new NamedRunnable(t1, r1), 
            new NamedRunnable(t2, r2));
}

public void execute(String t1, Runnable r1, String t2, Runnable r2, 
        String t3, Runnable r3) {
    execute(new NamedRunnable(t1, r1), 
            new NamedRunnable(t2, r2),
            new NamedRunnable(t3, r3));
}

// continue if you need more

public void customExecute() {
    execute("Action 1 passed", () -> sleep(1), "Other action passed", () -> sleep(2));
}
```

Here call looks cleaner, but it requires much more "library" code.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a variation that uses varargs and a higher-order function. It's simpler (but also less general) than Holger's. But it might be sufficient if all you want to do is print a string after executing a `Runnable`.

The idea is to have a function that creates a new `Runnable` by taking an existing one and printing a string after running it:

```
static Runnable runPrint(Runnable r, String msg) {
    return () -> {
        r.run();
        System.out.println(msg);
    };
}
```

Then you just pass several of these to your varargs-based `execute` method:

```
    execute(runPrint(() -> sleep(1), "first"),
            runPrint(() -> sleep(2), "second"),
            runPrint(() -> sleep(3), "third"));
```